# spring integration with jms, weblogic, message appears in queue even after message is consumed into channel

Tags: jms, spring-integration, weblogic12c

I am using spring integration with weblogic jms. my logic is to put the json object in jms queue, and consume it from queue into the channel, validate it and route it based on a particular field. if there is any error, do the fix and put it back into the queue. I have two issues. 1. when the message is consumed into the object, I still can see the  object as pending in administrative console of weblogic. 2. After fixing the validation, if put the modified object in the queue, I am getting the original object from queue.

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOutbound"
    channel="requestChannel"  connection-factory="queueConnectionFactory"
    destination="inputQueue" />
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="jmsInbound" connection-factory="queueConnectionFactory" 
    destination="inputQueue" channel="routingChannel" />

if (message.getHeaders().get("documentType").equals("sec"))
        routingChannels.add(outboundSecChannel);
    else if (message.getHeaders().get("documentType").equals("unds"))
        routingChannels.add(outboundFChannel);
    else if (message.getHeaders().get("documentType").equals("CH"))
        routingChannels.add(outboundAChannel);
    else{
        routingChannels.add(errorChannel);
    }
```

putting in channel using routing

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should distinguish the consuming part from producing to the separate threads. I don't tell that you have to switch to the transactions, but at least the simple acknowledge for the consumed message should be done.

Since you tell that you are going to putt the message back to the queue, that's definitely the fact to always acknowledge the consumed message independently of the error fact. So, what I suggest is something like to place a `QueueChannel` or an `ExecutorChannel` somewhere after `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` and before `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` to let them do their hard work with the WebLogic JMS in their own threads.

Comment: thank you @Artem, that served my need. I put the modified message as a new message.